# WCF Compression with .net 4

Tags: wcf, iis-7, .net-4.0, compression

I have read this [WCF Compression](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCF-Compression-Example-9ffab49c) article
I understand that for .net 4.0 WCF compression is available out of the box.

I can't find any clear explanation of how to use it, do I need to define any settings or change a binding? or it is compressed automatically?

I am using basicHttpBinding in IIS7. The option "enable dynamic compression" is set to true, but I don't get how the client knows to compress the requests and to decompress the response?

Any explanation including setting the binding to reduce message size will be appreciated. I am experiencing very bad performance when working on remote server with 4MB bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

> but I don't get how the client knows to compress the requests and to decompress the response??

It's all part of the HTTP spec.  Since WCF uses HTTP & IIS, it can leverage the built-in compression of the web server and client HTTP stack.

Check out section 14.3:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Basically, your client needs to send a header saying it supports compression.  Example:  `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`.  You can set this by following the instructions in your article for the WCF Client section.  Your client will then send out the right headers to the server.

Now on the server side, IIS will see that header, and it will compress the response...*if configured to do so*.  The article you linked tells you how to set up IIS for compression for WCF services.  The server will then send back a header to the client telling it the content is compressed: `Content-Encoding: gzip`.  The client will then decompress the response and go on its merry way.

That's pretty much it; it's just a matter of getting the client headers right and the server configured to send back a compressed response.  The article tells you how to do just that.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Note that compression has been added to WCF 4.5. It's covered here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You have to use a custom binding to enable it:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="BinaryCompressionBinding">
    <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip"/> 
    <httpTransport /> 
  </binding> 
</customBinding>
```

It only works with binary encoding. Also, you have to be aware of your scenario. If you are hosted in IIS, compression may already be on. See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmetzgar/archive/2011/04/29/automatic-decompression-in-wcf.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The compression sample is provided in .NET 4 WCF sample,

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459

This blog post explains it with more information,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmetzgar/archive/2011/03/10/compressing-messages-in-wcf-part-one-fixing-the-gzipmessageencoder-bug.aspx

There are other posts on MSDN blogs, like

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmetzgar/archive/2011/04/29/automatic-decompression-in-wcf.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When using an http encoding, a good way to enable the compression of responses (only) is by using the **[dynamic compression built-in to IIS7 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6855003/709537)**.

> but I don't get how the client knows to compress the requests and to decompress the response?

What follows is a description of what HTTP offers out of the box, which can be used together with the WCF HTTP(S) encodings. In addition to that, WCF 4.5 provides [gzip and deflate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.compressionformat.aspx) [compression of its binary encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889.aspx).

**Compressed responses** are part of the HTTP standard. In its request, the client signals to the server which compression methods (gzip, deflate, ...) it supports by means of the following header:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

The server, in its sole discretion, infinite wisdom and mysterious ways, is free to ignore that header and send the response uncompressed, or it may choose any one of the algorithms offered by the client, answering, say, with the following header and compress the response body.

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

To make matters more complicated, the server will probably also set the following header:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

This allows the server to omit the otherwise mandatory `Content-Length` header that, as HTTP headers in general, has to precede the HTTP body. (Setting the `chunked` encoding [affects the way the body gets encoded](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1).) So now it can compress the response body on-the-fly, i.e. spitting out bytes as they are compressed, without having to wait for the compression of the whole body to finish, just to be able to determine the content length of the compressed result. This can save a lot of memory on the server side. (The client side, however, is now left in the dark as to the total size of the compressed response, until it finished receiving the whole response, making it's decompression slightly less efficient)

---

Note however that using [`Accept-Encoding`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3) and [`Content-Encoding`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11), as I just described, to *transparently compress* responses was actually [a stupid idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11664307/709537), according to http co-author Roy Fielding and what should have been used instead is the following header in the request:

```
TE: gzip, deflate
```

And the server, if it chooses to perform compression, would add the following header to its response:

```
Transfer-Encoding: gzip, chunked
```

As before, `chunked` is necessary if the server wants to omit the `Content-Length`.

Otherwise, the [`TE`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.39)/[`Transfer-Encoding`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.41) combo is syntactically identical to the `Accept-Encoding`/`Content-Encoding` combo, but the meaning is different, as can be gleaned from [this longish discussion](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39727#c31).

The gist of the problem: TE/Transfer-Encoding makes compression a *transportation detail*, whereas Accept-Encoding/Content-Encoding denotes the compressed version as the actual data (*entity* in HTTP parlance), with a number of unfortunate ramifications regarding caching of requests, proxy-ing, etc. of the latter.

However, the TE/Transfer-Encoding ship sailed long time ago, and we are stuck with the AE/CE combo, which is supported by most clients and servers with a meaning that is in actuality closer to that of TE/TE

---

When it comes to **compressed requests** in HTTP, they are rarely used in practice, and there is no standard way for the client to figure out if a server supports it. Either you tell the client out-of-band (e.g. hard-coding) that the server understands compressed requests (and [configure the server appropriately](https://serverfault.com/a/56707/124382)). Or you have your client proactively try compression once, and if it yields a `400 Bad Request` (at least that's what an IIS 7.5 would return), you fall back to non-compressed requests.