# Compressing request body with python-requests?

Tags: python, http, gzip, python-requests

(This question is **not** about transparent decompression of `gzip`-encoded *responses* from a web server; I know that [`requests` handles that automatically](//docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/?highlight=multipart#binary-response-content).)

## Problem

I'm trying to POST a file to a RESTful web service. Obviously, `requests` makes this pretty easy to do:

```py
files = dict(data=(fn, file))
response = session.post(endpoint_url, files=files)
```

In this case, my file is in a really highly-compressible format (yep, XML) so I'd like to make sure that the **request** body is compressed.

The server claims to accept gzip encoding (`Accept-Encoding: gzip` in response headers), so I should be able to gzip the whole body request body, right?

## Attempted solution

Here's my attempt to make this work: I first construct the request and prepare it, then I go into the `PreparedRequest` object, yank out the `body`, run it through `gzip`, and put it back. (Oh, and don't forget to update the `Content-Length` and `Content-Encoding` headers.)

```
files = dict(data=(fn, file))
request = request.Request('POST',endpoint_url, files=files)

prepped = session.prepare_request(request)
with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as gzfile:
    gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzfile, mode="wb").write(prepped.body)
    prepped.headers['Content-Length'] = gzfile.tell()
    prepped.headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
    gzfile.seek(0,0)
    prepped.body = gzfile.read()
    response = session.send(prepped)
```

Unfortunately, the server is not cooperating and returns `500 Internal Server Error`. Perhaps it doesn't *really* accept `gzip`-encoded requests?

Or perhaps there is a mistake in my approach? It seems rather convoluted. Is there an easier way to do request body compression with `python-requests`?

**EDIT:** Fixed (3) and (5) from @sigmavirus24's [answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/28659930/20789) (these were basically just artifacts I'd overlooked in simplifying the code to post it here).

Comment: Request decompression is rather poorly supported by webservers and disabled for security reasons (vulnerability to [gzip bombs](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51071/zlib-deflate-decompression-bomb)). For apache, you need to enable it using [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html#input). Are you sure the server really supports it? `Accept-Encoding` is usually not sent by the server but by the client.

Comment: I am not really sure that the server supports gzip'ed requests, no. It seems inconsistent in its advertisement of this feature. Which makes it that much harder to figure out if in sending it a reasonable request...

Answer (score 6):

> Or perhaps there is a mistake in my approach?

I'm unsure how you arrived at your approach, frankly, but there's certainly a simpler way of doing this.

First, a few things:

1. The `files` parameter constructs a `multipart/form-data` body. So you're compressing something that the server potentially has no clue about.
2. `Content-Encoding` and `Transfer-Encoding` are two very different things. You want `Transfer-Encoding` here.
3. You don't need to set a suffix on your `NamedTemporaryFile`.
4. Since you didn't explicitly mention that you're trying to compress a `multipart/form-data` request, I'm going to assume that you don't actually want to do that.
5. Your call to `session.Request` (which I assume should be, `requests.Request`) is missing a method, i.e., it should be: `requests.Request('POST', endpoint_url, ...)`

With those out of the way, here's how I would do this:

```
# Assuming `file` is a file-like obj
with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as gzfile:
    gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzfile, mode="wb").write(file.read())
    headers = {'Content-Length': str(gzfile.tell()),
               'Transfer-Encoding': 'gzip'}
    gzfile.seek(0, 0)
    response = session.post(endpoint_url, data=gzfile, 
                            headers=headers)
```

Assuming that `file` has the `xml` content in it and all you meant was to compress it, this should work for you. You probably want to set a `Content-Type` header though, for example, you'd just do

```
 headers = {'Content-Length': gzfile.tell(),
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml',  # or 'text/xml'
            'Transfer-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

The `Transfer-Encoding` tells the server that the request is being compressed only in transit and it should uncompress it. The `Content-Type` tells the server how to handle the content once the `Transfer-Encoding` has been handled.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! I fixed #3 and #5, which were just artifacts of my attempt at simplifying the code to post it.

As for #1 and #4, I'm aware that I'm posting a `multipart/form-data` body: the service requires this in order to accept the file in its uncompressed form.

You're right that I'm definitely confused about the semantics of `Content-Encoding` as opposed to `Transfer-Encoding`. [Here is one of the clearer discussions that I've found](//stackapps.com/questions/916/why-content-encoding-gzip-rather-than-transfer-encoding-gzip)... any better explanation out there?

Comment: I was not worrying about the fact that the body is a `multipart/form-data` because I thought the effect of `Content-Encoding: gzip` would be to tell the server to transparently gunzip the **entire request body** before handling it in any way. Seems like this is a faulty assumption?

Comment: Yeah, your original code will mostly work then, but you'll want to set the `Transfer-Encoding`. Alternatively, if you don't want to hijack the request preparation part of requests, you can use the [requests-toolbelt](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt) to generate the body and appropriate headers and then gzip it with the proper Transfer-Encoding.

Comment: I don't believe T-E is going to help here; it has even less support than Content-Encoding in requests (and it also doesn't exist in HTTP/2).

Answer (score 1):

I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748142/receive-compressed-data-from-python-requests-in-express-js) that was marked as an exact duplicate. I was concernd with both ends of the transaction.

The code from sigmavirus24 wasn't a direct cut and paste fix, but it was the inspiration for this version.

Here's how my solution ended up looking:

### sending from the python end

```
import json
import requests
import StringIO
import gzip

url = "http://localhost:3000"
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/octet-stream"}
data = [{"key": 1,"otherKey": "2"},
        {"key": 3,"otherKey": "4"}]

payload = json.dumps(data)

out = StringIO.StringIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w") as f:
  f.write(json.dumps(data))
out.getvalue()

r = requests.post(url+"/zipped", data=out.getvalue(), headers=headers)
```

### receiving at the express end

```
var zlib = require("zlib");
var rawParser = bodyParser.raw({type: '*/*'});

app.post('/zipped', rawParser, function(req, res) {

    zlib.gunzip(req.body, function(err, buf) {
        if(err){
            console.log("err:", err );
        } else{
            console.log("in the inflate callback:",
                        buf,
                        "to string:", buf.toString("utf8") );
        }
    });

    res.status(200).send("I'm in ur zipped route");
});
```

There's a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/notionparallax/8dde9a2daee3dbe090bbb4eafb95ee7f) with more verbose logging included. This version doesn't have any safety or checking built in either.