# Compressing request and response soap message of wcf web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, compression

I refered this link: `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53718/Extending-WCF-Part-II`

I created proxy to call wcf method But after implementing this logic also I am getting following error:

```
Content Type application/x-gzip was not supported by service http://localhost/DeskWCF/Demo.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
```

If you have any way to compress soap messages of wcf then please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at these questions, and you should be able to get it working

[How to get gzip compression working in WCF 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680087/how-to-get-gzip-compression-working-in-wcf-4-5)
[How to get gzip compression working in WCF 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680087/how-to-get-gzip-compression-working-in-wcf-4-5)