# Enable compression in a self hosted WCF data service

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services, devextreme

I'm developing a web application using the devextreme library. This library supports OData as data source so in my server I have a WCF Data Service which is self-hosted. I would like to enable response compression in the service because with low connection speed it takes about 10 seconds to download the response in the client. Any suggestions?
p.s. If possible I would like to avoid using IIS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908110/compressing-request-and-response-soap-message-of-wcf-web-service