# How do I enable compression for WCF when using simple TCP?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am using WCF to transmit information between two identical copies of a program on separate computers, with the approach demonstrated on a single computer in the code below.  I know that .NET 4.5 [supports compression out of the box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889(v=vs.110).aspx) and I see an XML implementation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680087/), but I don't understand how to enable it in this case.  How can I modify the program below to use compression with the fewest/simplest changes?

```
// Reference to System.ServiceModel
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new DemoWcfServer();
        var handler = new DemoWcfHandler();

        Uri serviceUri = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost/SimpleWcfDemo");
        var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        binding.MaxBufferSize = 100000000;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 100000000;

        var host = new ServiceHost(server, serviceUri);
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDemoWcfServer), binding, "");
        host.Open();

        var cf = new DuplexChannelFactory<IDemoWcfServer>(handler, binding, new EndpointAddress(serviceUri));
        IDemoWcfServer serviceProxy = cf.CreateChannel();

        serviceProxy.DoStuff(BigString('T', 1000000));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static string BigString(char c, int n)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sb.Append(c);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IDemoWcfCallback))]
    public interface IDemoWcfServer
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoStuff(string content);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class DemoWcfServer : IDemoWcfServer
    {
        public void DoStuff(string content)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Content of " + content.Length + " length received remotely; processing...");
            IDemoWcfCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IDemoWcfCallback>();
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                callback.NotifyStuffComplete(BigString('R', 1000000));
            });
        }
    }

    public interface IDemoWcfCallback
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void NotifyStuffComplete(string content);
    }

    public class DemoWcfHandler : IDemoWcfCallback
    {
        public void NotifyStuffComplete(string content)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Response of " + content.Length + " length received");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the custom binding that includes compression (.NET 4.5+), replace this:

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.MaxBufferSize = 100000000;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 100000000;
```

with this:

```
var binding = new CustomBinding();
var be1 = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
be1.CompressionFormat = CompressionFormat.GZip;
binding.Elements.Add(be1);
var be2 = new TcpTransportBindingElement();
be2.MaxBufferSize = 100000000;
be2.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 100000000;
binding.Elements.Add(be2);
binding = new CustomBinding(binding);
```

The desired behavior can be verified with [Microsoft Message Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=44226) (or Wireshark presumably) by listening on the local loopback to port 808.  With compression, there are only 14 packets exchanged and none with a payload larger than 1200 bytes.  Without compression, there are 238 packets with many larger than 64k.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the [question your quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680087/) solves it by using a custom binding. You could do this yourself as explained in [this MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730305(v=vs.110).aspx).